# TukeyHSD after within factors ANOVA

Tags: r

I run the following commands

```
a1 <- aov(Ratio~(Condition*Event) + Error(Participant/(Condition*Event)), Data)
summary(a1)
```

That outputs the correct results (ANOVA tables etc).

When I run:

> TukeyHSD(a1,"Condition")

I get: Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : no applicable method for "TukeyHSD"

Why does the ANOVA work, but not TukeyHSD? Both within factor variables are strings (Condition has 3 levels and Event has 4 levels).

EDIT:
When I redo the aov without the Error term it works, however Tukey shows no significant difference between any of the pairs (The ANOVA was significant for Confidence). Does this mean that Tukey's is correcting for multiple comparisons?

Comment: maybe provide the `str` of your data.frame. Or better yet, provide a `dput()` of the relevant objects.

Comment: `aov()` with `Error()` returns a object with a class of `"aovlist" "listof"`. TukeyHSD apparently doesn't have a method for either of those classes.

Comment: Kevin, create an "answer" for what you just wrote so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: Less well known is the laercio package, which also performs the same test http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/laercio/laercio.pdf which may be a bit easier to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aov()` with `Error()` returns a object with a class of `"aovlist" "listof"`. TukeyHSD apparently doesn't have a method for either of those classes.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to traditional repeated-measures ANOVA for within-subject design, you might consider using linear mixed-effects approach. It is being increasingly used in the scientific community and avoids some of the ANOVA pitfalls while allowing for more complex error structures. With continuous response variable, the [nlme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) package is enough, but you can also use [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) which further allows to cope with categorical response variables. For multiple comparisons (including Tukey's post-hoc tests), then, the [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) package (see the `glht()` function) can be used with mixed-effects models fitted with `nlme::lme`, as described here: [Repeated Measures ANOVA using R](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/).

One short remark about your design: If your response (dependent) variable, `Ratio`, is a proportion or a bounded value, you may think of using a different link function.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(laercio)
some.aov <- aov(Ratio~(Condition*Event) + Error(Participant/(Condition*Event)), Data)
anova(some.aov)
LTukey(some.aov,"Condition")
```

Comment: It doesn't accept those kind of models, only standard models returned from `aov` without error structure (like `TukeyHSD`).